# Which part of this WHERE IN subquery is wrong? It produces no output

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is a valid query, which generates no results but it was shown by someone else that it has results. 
The question was 'What was the total monthly revenue for the top 50 products sold in July 2017 for each of the 11 months prior to July 2017?

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE("%m",date) AS Month, product.v2ProductName AS Product_Name, SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000 AS Total_Revenue, 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hit,
  UNNEST(hit.product) AS product
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170801' AND '20170630' AND totals.transactions >= 1
AND 
product.v2ProductName IN (
SELECT 
product.v2ProductName AS Product_Name
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hit,
  UNNEST(hit.product) AS product
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170731' AND totals.transactions >= 1
Group by product_Name
Order by SUM(totals.transactionRevenue)/1000000
LIMIT 50)
Group by PARSE_DATE("%m",date), Product_Name
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: If you can setup a **DB Fiddle** it will be easier for people to help you out. `https://www.db-fiddle.com/`

Comment: Would you be able to provide some data? So I can minimally reproduce the case

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. The dates were wrong:

```
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170801' AND '20170630'
```

It was supposed to be between *20160801* and *20170630*.